# Two instances of tomcat running same application create same sessionId for different users(?)

Tags: java, spring-mvc, session, tomcat

I am developing a session state server (like ASP.NET state server) which will store session data on different machine and serves whenever requested by web server. I know we can also use tomcat clustering and session replication for this purpose but still I want to go with session state server for some reasons.

To map session data session id is the key part but consider the case where tow tomcat servers are configured behind the LB with a same web application:
[image]

**In this case I wanted to know is there any chance that both tomcat instances will generate same session ID (JSESSIONID) for different users?** because I am planning to use session id generated by `HttpSession` as key part to store/serve the session data from state server.

Note: I have already created a new class by implementing `HttpSession` also implemented own HttpServletRequestWrapper and registered in filter chain.

Comment: See "[Tomcat Unique SessionId](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7650524/5221149)" about why unique session IDs are trouble-some, then read "[Apache Tomcat 8 Configuration Reference - The SessionIdGenerator Component](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/sessionidgenerator.html)" for how to control generation of session IDs, e.g. to implement your own session ID generator that includes a server-unique value in the ID.

Comment: You might have a look at [Tomcat Clustering](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/cluster-howto.html). The DeltaManager replicates the session when values change. Overwriting that class might help you solve your project.

Comment: @Andreas means as like shown in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15947964) i can generate my own session Id (may be generated by my state server API) and return it so that, that session Id will sent in cookie for `JSESSIONID`, am I understood it correctly? please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: @Amogh Simple adding a `<SessionIdGenerator>` tag in the `server.xml` file specifying a `jvmRoute` attribute would be a lot easier. Better yet, just specify the `jvmRoute` attribute on the [`<Engine>`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/config/engine.html#Common_Attributes) element.

Comment: @Andreas I have added `jvmRoute` in `Engine` as `<Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="jvm1">`, but I can't see jvmRoute added at the end of session id separated by a "." as mentioned in [docs](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/sessionidgenerator.html#Standard_Implementation)